# Searching for word fragments

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm trying to search in inbox by entering `content:Mover` and I get e-mails that contain single word `Mover`. But I also need e-mails that contain word `NetMover`. How to achieve that? `content:*Mover` not helps

Answer (score 0):

#### I also need e-mails that contain word `NetMover`

It's not directly possible, but there is a (messy) workaround:

> Outlook 2016 will execute a partial word search only if the search sting is at the beginning of the word. For example, in a word called ‘Melbourne’, Outlook 2016 will be able to search the word if the search string is something like ‘Melb’ or Melbour’ etc.
>
> However, if the search sting is in the middle of a word or at the end of a word, Outlook 2016 will not be able to search the word.
>
> To do a partial search for a search string in the middle of the word or at the end of the word, you need to use Advanced Find option in Outlook 2016. Follow these steps to execute a partial search in Outlook 2016 based on Advanced Find. However, this is the only option in Outlook 2016 to execute a partial search.
>
> - Click inside the search box in Outlook 2016.
> - Click on Search Tools > Advanced Find > Advanced tab.
> - Click on Field > Frequently-used fields > Subject.
> - Select Contains in Condition drop-down box.
> - In Value add your search string.
> - Click on Add to List.
>
> You may select the search string and click on New Search to execute a partial search.

In your case you need to change the value `Frequently-used fields` as appropriate to search the email content.

Source [Outlook 2016 partial search](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10/outlook-2016-partial-search/555ef7e8-fd67-4d80-a22f-eb8cc89eff21)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Instant Search query commands reference](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/searchcommands.htm)